# Record any application behavior or script in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to record my application behavior ex login in gui mode then want to find behavior and doing performance testing on that application using JMeter . so please help me to find out which plug ins or script to record particular application

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) can record only [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) or [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocols so if your "any application" uses HTTP or HTTPS - it can be recorded using JMeter.

For web browsers the comprehensive instructions are provided in the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) official documentation

For other applications i.e. desktop, mobile, etc. you need to

1. Configure the application to use JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder as the proxy. If application doesn't have separate proxy configuration most probably it respects underlying operating system settings so you need to set the operating system to use JMeter as the proxy
2. In case of HTTPS you will also need to install JMeter's certificate into your operating system trusted certificates storage

The exact instructions depend on the operating system and the technology (ies) the application is built in, high-level instructions for Windows desktop applications can be found in i.e. [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) article.